# Android: View.inflate not showing the second layout on screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

Two Layout files:

activity_maps.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jawadh.startthreeproject.MapsActivity" />
    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
</FrameLayout >
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_container"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSource"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In my activity, once the mapsActivity gets loaded and working fine. I want to load the view of second.xml over the exisiting view.
So, I am trying this:

```
 final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.second,null);

        final Button button = (Button)frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);;
        button.setBackgroundColor((Color.GRAY));
        button.setText("Direction");
        button.setY(300);
        button.setX(300);

        TextView textViewSource = (TextView)frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewSource);
        textViewSource.setText(place.getAddress().toString());
        textViewSource.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textViewSource.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Expectation: This last part of code should put te second.xml view(framelayout) over the exisiting view.

Comment: You didn't attach `frameLayout` to the view hierarchy.

Comment: can you explain a little more? 
How to attach framelayout to the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: DO NOT use application context for inflating views!**

You created the second layout here:

```
final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.second,null);
```

Now you have to attach it to view hierarchy. Fragment container sounds nice enough:

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
container.addView(frameLayout, lp);
```

#### EDIT

Alternatively you could inflate AND attach new view in one go like so:

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.second, container);
```

...because `FrameLayout` will provide you with these `LayoutParams` by default:

```
/**
 * Returns a set of layout parameters with a width of
 * {@link android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams#MATCH_PARENT},
 * and a height of {@link android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams#MATCH_PARENT}.
 */
@Override
protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Comment: your first solution works. The one u provided in EDIT wouldn't take third argument as R.id.fragment_container.

Comment: @wadhwa94 Fixed. And I didn't notice it before - read the new warning.

Comment: can you explain or share any link with reference to **Warning: DO NOT use application context for inflating views!**

Comment: **1)** Activity context has theme attributes. You can't inflate AppCompat widgets reliably without an AppCompatActivity context (simply put). On top of that activity context can open links from text views. App context would crash doing that. **2)** Always go for the nearest context available. Are you building a *light* themed app with *dark* dialogs? `builder.getContext()` will give you what you need. Are you using *dark* toolbar over *light* activity? Use `toolbar.getContext()` if you're e.g. inflating custom title view within the toolbar. This will ensure correct text color and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a little more detail was required.
And hey, whatever you are doing, you are not doing it the best way.

Anyways, you inflated the view in `frameLayout` but you are not adding this to the present parent.
Am not sure what exactly you want to achieve but I think you are missing that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace view by set visibility to **GONE**. 
In your case, you should create one xml file instead of two. In xml file, take one linearlayout with orientation vertical. In this linearlayout take two framelayouts.When your activity starts, set second framelayout's visibility to **GONE**.  When map is loaded in first framelayout, set it's visibility to **GONE** and second framelayout's visibility to **VISIBLE**. When you do this, second framelayout will automatically replace first framelayout.
sample code:

```
 private LinearLayout llLogin;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        llLogin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loginlayout);
        llLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I wouldn't be covering the entire portionso i need two separate xml as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: In your question, you said you want to load the view of second.xml over the exisiting view.So actually what you want? Do you want to remove map view or not?

Comment: no i want to partially cover it like 30% or in such a way